# How do you play real-time data on sounddevice?

Tags: multithreading, audio, real-time

Don't ask why, but I want to calculate the average intensity of a pixel of live webcam footage and play it with sounddevice in real time - at most a one-second delay.

I am using Python, and I am getting the video camera footage using OpenCV. I know how to find the average pixel intensity and how to play sounds with sounddevice the problem is putting those two things together so that they happen at the same time.

Sorry, the question wasn't clear before. Please, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is this "sensor?" What do the "stream of numbers" that you get from it mean? Why would it make sense to convert those numbers into sound? What is the platform that your code will run on? What operating system? You said, "haven't found any way of getting data from the sensor _while also_ playing it as a sound." Do you know how to get the data, but not how to play sound? or do you not know how to do either of those things? or do you know how to do both, but not at the same time? Have you tried anything yet? Where is your code? Voting to close unless you provide more details.

Comment: In order to produce a sound, you’ll need to be able to generate sample values at the sound card’s sample-rate (eg 48,000 values per second, although it can often be set to one of a few other rates instead).  Do you have an algorithm in mind to generate those values from your pixel?  (I assume your camera isn’t outputting frames fast enough to simply copy 48000 pixel values over per second)

Comment: I was planning to play the sound of one frame until the next one became available. Anyway, sounddevice lets you choose a sample rate for audio. I should just be able to set it equal to the video’s frame rate.